# PHP: Check if MySQL TABLE already exists as an error condition?

Tags: php, mysql

How in PHP would I check for a condition if a MySQL TABLE already exists and it shouldn't and need to abort but with a message that's meaningful? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the table. You should get an error: `1050 "table already exists"`.

Or you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525801/2427840

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_` - functions are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

To check if a table exists you can use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database-name]' 
AND table_name = '[table-name]';
```

Comment: +1 for using the `information_schema` and specifying `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use:-

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name'");
$tableExist = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
if($tableExist)
echo "Table Exist";
```