# Check if table was newly created or not in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have a command to create table in the database. I want to know whether a new table is created or not. Below given is my command.

```
 $command = $connection->createCommand(
     "
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$tbName."` LIKE `question`;
        INSERT INTO `".$tbName."` SELECT * FROM `question`;

     "
    )->execute();
    echo $command;
   if($command!==0){
    echo "Success";}
   else echo "Table already created";
```

But this always prints "Table already created" even if it is not there in the database.

Comment: why u can't check tbl existence with another qry, just like select 1 from tblname; it ll give result with true or false...

Comment: That will always give me true na?I want to check that if it is newly created or not. I want to write a one time action there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CDbCommand::execute()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#execute-detail) returns the number of rows affected by the sql statement. Since creating a table doesn't create any rows the result will always be `0`. The same goes for [`CDbCommand::createTable()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#createTable-detail). Therefore as user1844933 mentioned, you should use another query to check whether the table exists:

```
$result = $connection->createCommand("SHOW TABLES LIKE :table_name")->execute(array('table_name'=>$table_name));
$tableExists = $result > 0;
```

Code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525801/428543

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to use CdbCommand::createTable for this. See:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#createTable-detail

Answer (score 0):

There are severals way to check if table exist, so :

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name'"))==1) {
  echo "Table exists";
}
```

Another way is to make select from table:

```
$value = mysql_query('select 1 from `table_name`')

if($value !== FALSE)
{
   echo "Table exists";
}
```