# MYSQL: Check if table exists does not work

Tags: mysql, exists

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N`db_291702_2`.`aaCoRrankingDateManage`, N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Table Exists'
END
```

What is wrong with this? Why do I get errors?
Neither of the suggested ways in [how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-sql-server/](http://sqlhints.com/2014/04/13/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-sql-server/) works for me.

PS. "does not work" means errors like

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''db_291702_2'.'aaCoRrankingDateManage' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Additional info:
I am using phpMyAdmin, my two databases are called `db_291702_1` and `db_291702_2`, the latter has two tables, one of them is called `aaCoRrankingDateManage`

Comment: single quotes are for encapsulation of strings, not table names

Comment: look at the code coloring. you have an odd number of single quotes, which will trouble the sql

Comment: jup you're right, edited it, doesn't change anything though

Comment: I can't seem to find any working exemple of MySQL with `OBJECT_ID()`, neither can I find it on the official MySQL reference... maybe it's not a MySQL function? this guy has similar problem: http://board.issociate.de/thread/260989/Detect-if-table-exists-from-within-MySQL.html

Comment: I think the accepted answer can help you even more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The given source code is no MySQL Code.

Comment: MySQL uses SQL. Do you mean this is T-SQL?

Comment: in Mysql  use this `if exists table_name1,table_name2...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape table or column names then use backticks

```
select `group` from table1
```

A static string must be included in quotes

```
select * from users where name = 'john'
```

And the syntax of every DB engine is a little bit different. The above works for MySQL, but SQL-Server has a different syntax. There you use brackets `[]` to escape names.

But you only need to escape names if you use reserved words. You don't have to escape everything.