# Create database if not exists just once

Tags: java, database, jdbc

This is my code, this code should be execute just one time, But when my database already exist, The `database created` message has been displayed!

I want to see message just when database really created, not every time.

```
public static boolean createDatabase() throws Exception {
    String query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS LIBRARY3";
    Statement st = null;
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2000");
    st = con.createStatement();
    if (st.executeUpdate(query) == 1) { // Then database created
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database created");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code always returns `true`, Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its MySQL you need to check if database exists to take decision weather the database was really created

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'LIBRARY3'
```

Comment: What is schema name of my database?

Comment: UNKNOWN COLUMN 'LIBRARY4' IN 'field list'

Comment: `SCHEMA_NAME` should be the same, copy and paste the same query

Comment: I try this: `SELECT LIBRARY3 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'LIBRARY3'`, But has same error.

Comment: try this `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'LIBRARY3'`

Answer (score 0):

It returns true because you are asking mysql to create the database only if it exists, so, if it exists there is no error, it just does not create it. What you can do is try to create it and, if it fails, check that the reason is that the database alreyady existed.

```
try {
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    String sql = "CREATE DATABASE DBNAME";
    //To delete database: sql = "DROP DATABASE DBNAME";
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
    System.out.println("Database created!");
} catch (SQLException sqlException) {
    if (sqlException.getErrorCode() == 1007) {
        // Database already exists error
        System.out.println(sqlException.getMessage());
    } else {
        // Some other problems, e.g. Server down, no permission, etc
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // No driver class found!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is successful each time. Do a separate query to check if the table exists and return message based on that result.

Read more about how to check whether a table exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way to do it:

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'LIBRARY3';
```

If `LIBRARY3` dont exist, you will get an empty string.