# Why is my if statement always returning false

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that checks if a table exists and if it does not then it creates one. The table gets create fine and the data goes in correctly. Once a table has been created and encounters the script I use the test again. However it always returns true and runs the create table script.Can anyone explain why.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$scriptot = ($_POST["ohyeah"]);
$scriptname = ($_POST["scriptname"]);
$y = 1;
$scriptnamed = "".$scriptname."equip";
$r= 1;
$scriptot = $scriptot + 1;

echo $scriptnamed;


$val = mysql_query("select 1 from specifics");
echo $val;
if($val !== FALSE)
{
    echo 'its there';
}
else
{
   echo 'No table Found';//always runs this even if exists
// sql to create table
$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE specifics (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 equiplist varchar(255),
 stage varchar(255),

PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never actually executing the `CREATE` query, at least not in this code snippet. This should mean that your `SELECT` query is always running on a non-existent table.

```
mysql_query($sql1);
```

Furthermore, if all you want to do with your `SELECT` is to check if a table exists or not, have a look at this answer for a cleaner way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525801/4652136

Answer (score 0):

In your `IF` statement, your query returns `1`. Then so `$val=1`. So by substitution in your `IF` statement `1!==FALSE` which is definitely true. Thus it will always run `echo 'its there';`.

```
$val = mysql_query("select 1 from specifics");
echo $val;
if($val !== FALSE)
{
    echo 'its there';
}
else
{
   echo 'No table Found';
```

Try this:

```
$val = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM information_schema.tables
                    WHERE table_schema = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE' 
                    AND table_name = 'specifics';");
echo $val;
if($val == 1)
{
    echo 'its there';
}
else
{
   echo 'No table Found';
```

Comment: it runs no table found? shouldi not be using select 1?

Comment: Who down voted me? I am trying to get this to work with the help I have had. Currently the table has stopped creating in the first place soI need to sort this