# Return results, if table does not already exist create one

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Need help with the following code

```
 function getAllUser()
{
    $sqlShow = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'users'"; 
    $result = $this->conn->select($sqlShow);
         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $selectresult = $this->conn->select($sqlSelect);
          return $selectresult;   
    } else {
    $sqlCreate =    "CREATE TABLE `users` (
                                                  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                                                  `userName` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
                                                  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                                                  `firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                                                  `lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
                                                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4";
    $createresult = $this->conn->select($sqlCreate);
        $output["type"] = "No current results, the table has now been created"; 
    }
}
```

I am getting a Fatal error that the table already exists, I don't understand where I have gone wrong in my code, appreciate any help that can be provided.

**Solution:**

```
    function getAllUser()
{
    $sqlShow = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wpiy_wpbs_bookings_temp'";
    $result = $this->conn->select($sqlShow);
    
         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM wpiy_wpbs_bookings_temp";
                        $selectresult = $this->conn->select($sqlSelect);
                        return $selectresult;   
         }else  if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
                        $output["message"] = "0 records";   
        } else {
                        $sqlCreate =    "CREATE TABLE `wpiy_wpbs_bookings_temp` (
```

Comment: If an [exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) (mysqli_sql_exception) is thrown, you can try/catch it. Also note, a exception behaves different from [error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php).

Comment: What's the bigger picture here? It's a bit unusual that you don't know in advance whether a table exists.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I have created an import capability where I can select a csv file and upload it into my database. I run a select query first to see if the table exists. If it exists then the import will occur, if it does not exist I will run a function that will create the table. Instead of the able 'Table does not exist' appearing I am getting a fatal error instead.

Comment: If the user table is missing it looks like the setup was not complete or any migration was not run before. This should not be catched within the code, but in a health check.

Comment: Run a query to check if the table exists like this -> SHOW TABLES LIKE '$tableName', and check if the output contains one or more table. if it doesn't it means such table doesnt exist. ($result->num_rows > 0) Reference this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception

Comment: For an import-time sanity check, you could catch the `mysqli_sql_exception` exception as already said and verify whether the exception code or SQL State matches [ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_no_such_table). But it feels more natural to make explicit checks during the import setup phase, and I'm sure the code will also be easier to write.

Comment: @FreeKrishna, With ($result->num_rows > 0) would the result for a table that does not exist and a table with no records produce the same result? If so, would  ($result->num_rows !== FALSE)  be a better solution?

Comment: You can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. But if the existing table has a different definition from what you're trying to create, that could cause other problems. You could do `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` first.

Comment: @zeroanarchy You edited the question and I don't think it makes sense any more. Do you still get a fatal error about a non-existing table? If so, in which of the 3 queries?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, sorry the thread was shut for any further comment unless I changed the question as Stack Overflow believed it was similar to other questions on much older versions which it wasn't. I finally found a way around the problem being that three possible results could be returned 1. The table did not exist, 2. The table existed however it contained no records and 3. The table existed with records. The solution was as follows: Solution has been posted in the above question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Apologies the question was closed before I could credit anyone for assistance.